# Global Region Restrictions of accessing Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Google Cloud Platform documentation is pretty solid in regards to zone/region access restrictions in regards to Cloud SQL, however Cloud Datastore documentation is limited.

Are there REGION restrictions on Datastore?

For example:

Can ComputeEngine or AppEngine resources in North America, EMEA, ASIA all access the same Datastore with uniform performance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The datastore is a so-called global service, same as Cloud storage , and is replicated over zones and regions. Instances and disks are examples of zonal resources.

In short, no : there are no regional/zonal restrictions to access the cloud datastore. Read performance will be probably be the same over different zones/regions.

Comment: any link to support this would be great

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/